# How can I load a JSON file inside a javascript class

Tags: javascript, json, class

I tried to load a JSON file inside a js class. The loaded data is available ony inside the function.

```
 class MakePage {
     constructor() {
        var request=new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET','daten.json');
        request.responseType='json';
        request.send();
        request.onload=function() {
            this.daten=request.response;
            alert(this.daten[1].Name); // this works
        }       
    }
    test(name) {
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML=this.daten[1].Name;
    }
}

page=new MakePage();
page.test("xyz"); //  TypeError: this.daten is undefined
```

How can I store the loaded data in a class member?

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers.
I tried self=this, bind(this) and the arrow operator, but I always get the same TypeReference error.

Comment: @31piy it's a `this` problem.

Comment: @sjahan -- May be, but even if you solve that, the code will still not work until the AJAX has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your callback function by an arrow function. 
When you do this:

```
this.daten=request.response
```

`this` is not what you think it is ;)
Using an arrow function won't alter the value of `this` and it will actually be what you expect.

```
class MakePage {
     constructor() {
        var request=new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET','daten.json');
        request.responseType='json';
        request.send();
        request.onload = () => {
            this.daten=request.response;
            alert(this.daten[1].Name); // this works
        }       
    }
    test(name) {
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML=this.daten[1].Name;
    }
}
```

Another way to do this is to use `bind`.

```
    request.onload=function() {
        this.daten=request.response;
        alert(this.daten[1].Name); // this works
    }       
    request.onload = request.onload.bind(this);
```

And don't forget to read the doc to understand how it works under the hood: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

The `this` inside your `request.onload=function()` refers to the wrong scope.

Either use an arrow function like `request.onload = () => {}` (recommended), or save a reference to the outer scope by doing `const self = this` somewhere in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe try to replace

```
request.onload=function() {
    this.daten=request.response;
    alert(this.daten[1].Name); // this works
}
```

by an arrow function

```
request.onload=()=> {
    this.daten=request.response;
    alert(this.daten[1].Name); // this works
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with a reference to this in the callback function:

```
 class MakePage {
     constructor() {
        var request=new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET','daten.json');
        request.responseType='json';
        request.send();
        self=this;
        request.onload=function() {
            self.daten=request.response;
            alert(self.daten[1].Name); // this works
        }       
    }
    test(name) {
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML=this.daten[1].Name;
    }
 }
```